# Merge multiple rows into one with total - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a stock database from invoice database. My invoice database looks like this:

```
  invoiceNo  |  date   |  supplier  |  productID  |  productName  |  qty
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  I0001      |  9/21   |  ABC       |     0001    |  yz           |  23
  I0001      |  9/21   |  ABC       |     0023    |  xy           |  42
  I0002      |  9/24   |  DEF       |     2106    |  pq           |  60
  I0003      |  9/30   |  ABC       |     0023    |  xy           |  32
```

In stock database, I want to merge several rows contain same product into one row and sum the quantity. So, it will look like this:

```
  productID  |  productName  |  stock  
---------------------------------------
  0001       |  yz           |  23
  0023       |  xy           |  74
  2106       |  pq           |  60
```

Is it possible to do that? I've been searching around and found about `CONCAT` or `JOIN`, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: *"I've been searching around and found about CONCAT or JOIN, but I'm not sure about it."* - You're not sure how; did you try out any of the examples in the manuals? (and possible tutorials).

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `GROUP BY` statement.

```
SELECT productID, productName, sum(qry)
  FROM [your table]
GROUP BY productID, productName
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work by grouping rows with same productname and sum their quantities

```
 SELECT productID ,productName,SUM(qty) AS stock
 FROM name of table
 GROUP BY productName,productID;
```